# MS Paint sharing violation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to open an image that is in a picture box with MS Paint, modify it with Paint, and then close Paint and see the modifications on the image in the picture box.

I am able to open the image with the following code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string picLocate = pictureBox2.ImageLocation.ToString();

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    procInfo.FileName = ("mspaint.exe");
    procInfo.Arguments = picLocate; //Full Path to an image

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo);
}
```

While in MS Paint, I modify the image and go to save the changes.  When I click Save, an error message box says there is a sharing violation and I am not able to save the image with the modifications.

I am not certain what process I should use to get around the error message.

Comment: Are you having the file still open in your application? Check with e.g. procmon who did not close the file when paint was accessing it.

Comment: Setting the PictureBox's image with the ImageLocation property or by assigning the Image property with Image.FromFile() causes a lock on the file that prevents the file from being overwritten.  That lock exists until Dispose() is called on the image.  Google "bitmap deep copy" to find alternatives.

Comment: Following Hans Passant's thinking, you could try using Image.FromFile to load the image into a Bitmap object and the file won't be locked. Also releases the resources associated with it. This should resolve the sharing conflict issue when saving image changes.